# Type Error in function

Tags: postgresql, geolocation, geometry, postgis

I am using this query

```
select ST_Segmentize((st_transform(way,3785),100)) from planet_osm_line where road_id = 1640527
```

And this is the database structure

```
 z_order            | integer                     | 
 way_area           | real                        | 
 way                | geometry(LineString,900913) | 
 road_id            | integer                     | not null default nextval('planet_osm_line_road_id_seq'::regclass)
Indexes:
    "planet_osm_line_pkey1" PRIMARY KEY, btree (road_id)
    "planet_osm_line_index" gist (way)
    "planet_osm_line_pkey" btree (osm_id)
```

And the error is

```
No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

What should I do. I guess function is correct and I checked from documentation page attribute types also match(geometry, meters).
Just to be clear 3785 is used to convert into meters.

Answer (score 0):

That was silly. Just removed the extra braces and voila!